# Did Petra Klamm-Rothberger, from German Green Party, say that Maria Ladenburger had to be killed as raped women are killed in Afghanistan?

Tags: sexual-abuse, germany

I'm giving the url for the google translation of two sites that offer the claim, to check for additional details in addition, if necessary, for checking if the claim is true or not.

This is one source:

[Source 1.](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alertadigital.com%2F2016%2F12%2F12%2Funa-dirigente-del-partido-verde-justifica-el-asesinato-de-una-joven-alemana-por-un-afgano-es-costumbre-en-afganistan-que-una-mujer-violada-sea-condenada-a-muerte%2F)

This is another source.

[Source 2.](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmoselkurier.de%2F%3Fp%3D235)

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: No, that's standard right wing fake news, and your question is looks like promotion for said right wing fake news. http://www.mimikama.at/allgemein/fake-news-moselkurier2/ it was originally published on this obvious fake news site: http://moselkurier.de/

Comment: Google returns no search results for "Petra Klamm-Rothberger" published before December 4, 2016. Either this person does not exist, or she has never been mentioned on the Internet before this story. Also, the [twitter account](http://moselkurier.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/klammrothberger-700x437.jpg) from which she supposedly said this does not exist and cannot have existed because Twitter handles [can only contain](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299) alphanumeric characters and underscores (no dash/hyphen characters allowed)

Answer (score 3):

No.

Apart from the evidence mentioned in the comments - neither Petra Klamm-Rothberger nor her Twitter Account are mentioned on the internet before December 4th - and the fact that the message is longer than twitter actually allows, the [German Newspaper Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/netzwelt/web/fake-news-in-deutschland-was-wir-ueber-das-phaenomen-wissen-a-1125498.html) says that this is a fake story, fabricated by a fake news site:

> In unserer postfaktischen Zeit ist es schwer geworden, den Überblick zu behalten. [...] Das zeigte sich, als in den vergangenen Tagen ein erfundenes Zitat einer nichtexistenten Grünen-Politikerin namens Petra Klamm-Rothberger herumging.
>   [...]
>   Es gibt keine Grünen-Politikerin namens Petra Klamm-Rothberger, sie war vom "Mosel-Kurier" fabriziert worden.

My translation:

> In times of post-truth politics, it is getting more difficult to keep an overview. The recent example of an invented quote by a non-existing politician of the Green Party named Petra Klamm-Rothberger shows this.
>   [...]
>   There is no politician of the Green party named Petra Klamm-Rothberger, the "Mosel-Kurier" made her up.